# Add value to a column acorrding to index with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing different queries from which I get 3 different columns(date_1, date_2, date_3). I need them in one Dataframe, so im using concat function for that. Im getting this:

```
resultado = pd.concat([date_1, date_2, date_3], axis=1)

     date_1            date_2            date_3
01/01/2009 0:00  01/01/2009 00:00   01/01/2009 0:00
01/01/2009 0:10  01/01/2009 00:10   01/01/2009 0:10
01/01/2009 0:20  01/01/2009 00:20   01/01/2009 0:30
01/01/2009 0:30  01/01/2009 00:30   01/01/2009 0:40
01/01/2009 0:40  01/01/2009 00:50   01/01/2009 0:50
01/01/2009 0:50               NaT               NaT
```

But what I want/need is something like this. Add the column value according to the index

```
     date_1            date_2            date_3
01/01/2009 0:00  01/01/2009 00:000  01/01/2009 0:00
01/01/2009 0:10  01/01/2009 00:10   01/01/2009 0:10
01/01/2009 0:20  01/01/2009 00:20               NaT
01/01/2009 0:30  01/01/2009 00:30   01/01/2009 0:30
01/01/2009 0:40               NaT   01/01/2009 0:40
01/01/2009 0:50  01/01/2009 00:50   01/01/2009 0:50
```

Comment: The thing is we need `date_1, date_2, date_3` with index so we can think of how something like that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can align data by `DatetimeIndex`:

```
#get all columns in list
sers = [date_1['date_1'], date_2['date_2'], date_3['date_3']]
#convert data to datetime
sers = [pd.to_datetime(x) for x in sers]
#create DatetimeIndex for align Series, remove NaNs rows and last remove Index
resultado = pd.concat([x.to_frame().set_index(x) for x in sers], axis=1)
resultado = resultado.dropna(how='all').reset_index(drop=True)
print (resultado)
               date_1              date_2              date_3
0 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2009-01-01 00:00:00
1 2009-01-01 00:10:00 2009-01-01 00:10:00 2009-01-01 00:10:00
2 2009-01-01 00:20:00 2009-01-01 00:20:00                 NaT
3 2009-01-01 00:30:00 2009-01-01 00:30:00 2009-01-01 00:30:00
4 2009-01-01 00:40:00                 NaT 2009-01-01 00:40:00
5 2009-01-01 00:50:00 2009-01-01 00:50:00 2009-01-01 00:50:00
```